# Why is the input box in my popup editor of my KendoUI grid not populating?

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I'm using the KendoUI for ASP.NET Core to work with data within my web application.  I have a grid that uses a custom popup editr.  This is accomplished with the following code:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Sale>()
                    .Name("salesGrid")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(p => p.CreatedDate).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.Status).Width(180);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.Seller).Width(150);                            
                    })
                    .ToolBar(toolBar =>
                    {
                        toolBar.Create().Text("Add Transaction");            
                    })                    
                    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).AdditionalViewData(new { vid = vesselid}).TemplateName("EditSalePopup"))
                    .Pageable()
                    .Sortable()                    
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()                        
                        .PageSize(20)
                        .ServerOperation(false)                        
                        .Model(model =>
                        {
                            model.Id(p => p.Id);
                            model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);
                            model.Field(p => p.CreatedDate).Editable(false);
                        })
                        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadSales", "Vessel").Data("GetVesselId"))
                        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateSale", "Vessel"))
                        .Create(create => create.Action("CreateSale", "Vessel").Data("GetVesselId"))
                        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteSale", "Vessel"))
                    ))
```

You'll notice that the edit code has both an additional value to be passed defined and the name of the editor template itself

```
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).AdditionalViewData(new { vid = vesselid}).TemplateName("EditSalePopup"))
```

The `vesselId` is taken from viewdata at the top of my page, the value is confirmed and can be seen.

```
@model Vessel     
@{ 
    string vesselid = Model.Id.ToString();
}
```

Here is the code for my custom editor which lives in the Shared/EditorTemplates folder

```
@model Sale

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="md-form form-group">
                <p>@ViewData["vid"]</p>
                <input type="text" asp-for="VesselId" value="@ViewData["vid"]" />                        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea is that when you click on the `add transaction` on the grid, you get this custom editor with the `vesselid` input box populated with the id of the vessel.  To test that the value is passed to the editor correclty I added a `<p>` with the `viewdata["vid"]` and I can clearly see that the ID is passed correctly, however, the input below it doesn't populate itself with the ID from `ViewData` it always shows `0`.

To investigate this I look at the input as it was rendered in the browser and it looks like this:

```
<input type="text" value="10577" data-val="true" data-val-required="The VesselId field is required." id="VesselId" name="VesselId" data-bind="value:VesselId">
```

As you can see from the rendered code the value is there and correct but the input still shows `0`.  Can anyone help me with understanding what's going wrong here and why I can't use the Id as defined?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand regarding popup editors is that they are serialized once on the server with a model that has the default values and after that it is reused on the client by plugging the values of the grid's model in.

So one thing you could do is add that field to the grid model. Another thing you can do is handle the grid's edit event and update the model or DOM at edit time:

```
...
.Events(ev =>
{
   ev.Edit("onGridEdit");
})
...


<script type="text/javascript">

    function onGridEdit(e) {
        // Update the grid's model or set the value of a hidden, etc.
        var uid = $(".k-edit-form-container").closest("[data-role=window]").data("uid");
        var model = $("#salesGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(uid);
        model.set("VesselId", vesselid);  
    }

</script>
```

Yet another way is to use [MVVM binding](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/value).